# Deleting images with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, paperclip

I'm trying to delete each single image uploaded for a model (work has many images) but now my code works like this: I have three images uploaded in a work, I want to delete just one but when I check the image's checkbox and submit the update action it will delete all the three images.

Here is my work model's code:

```
  before_save :destroy_image?

  belongs_to :category
  has_many :images, :as => :assetable, :class_name => "Work::Image", :dependent =>    :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['attachment'].blank? }

  def image_delete
    @image_delete ||= "0"
  end

 def image_delete=(value)
   @image_delete = value
 end

private
   def destroy_image?
    self.images.clear if @image_delete == "1"
   end


end


class Work::Image < Asset
   has_attached_file :attachment, :styles => {:small => "200x150>", :large =>    "400x300>"},
:url  => "/uploads/works/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
:path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/works/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

end
```

I think the problem is that delete all images

```
self.images.clear if @image_delete == "1"
```

but I don't understand how to fix it. I hope in your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `:allow_destroy` options of [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) instead.

And in your form something like this:

```
<% @work.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :images, image do |image_fields| %>
    <%= image_tag image.url(:small) %>
    <%= image_fields.check_box :_destroy %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes i use already `:allow_destroy` in work model and in the form view i got this
`<%- @work.images.each do |image| %>

  <%= image_tag image.url(:small) %>
<%= f.check_box(:image_delete) %>
<% end %>`

Comment: You don't need these `image_delete` stuffs at all. `:allow_destroy` will destroy the records for you. I've updated the view in the answer to fit yours.

Comment: you are right! i change my model with
`accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['attachment'].blank? }`
and my view in
`<%- @work.images.each do |image| %>
  
  <%= fields_for :images, image do |image_fields| %>
    <%= image_tag image.url(:small) %>
    <%= image_fields.check_box :attachment_delete %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>`
but i got this error: `undefined method 'attachment_delete'`

Comment: There was an error. The field is `:_destroy` as mentioned in the doc. I fixed the answer.

Comment: anythings happen when i check the image to delete and submit request rails says successfull update but nothings change, i try to set `:destroy` instead `:_destroy` and it give me this error `undefined method `to_i`, can you tell me why? thanks

Comment: The field is `:_destroy`. You may need the id of the image in a hidden field. I added it to the answer.

Comment: nothing again, the render of the form is `<input id="images_id" name="images[id]" type="hidden" value="3" />
     <img alt="Senza-titolo-1" src="/uploads/works/3/small/Senza-titolo-1.jpg?1307011687" />
     <input name="images[_destroy]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="images__destroy" name="images[_destroy]" type="checkbox" value="1" />

   `

Comment: I forgot the `f.` before `fields_for` (the one that comes from the `form_for`). It should work now. Your inputs should have names like `work[images_attributes][0][_destroy]`

Comment: ok, right for the first input here is the code `<img src="/uploads/works/3/small/Senza-titolo-1.jpg?1307011687" alt="Senza-titolo-1">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="work[images_attributes][0][_destroy]">
<input id="work_images_attributes_0__destroy" type="checkbox" value="1" name="work[images_attributes][0][_destroy]">` like your wrote the name but the image can't be deleted.

Comment: yes it works!! but i don't want that the system save an empty record to db when the input image is blank... is it possible to fix this? thanks so much

Comment: Great. The problem is your input image is also blank when you delete. Maybe something like `:reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['attachment'].blank? and attributes['_destroy'] == '0' }`

Comment: :-(  it still save blank input image, but it happens only when i save a NEW record but not in editing, i hope it helps!

Comment: Check the value of the params in the log and adapt `:reject_if` accordingly.

Comment: in the app there is a link_to_add function that add images input and it creates also a hidden field that is named `work[images_attributes][1][_destroy]` with `value = false` and so i change `attributes['_destroy'] == "false"` it works but when there is an existing image and i want to add another the system overwrite the image deleting the previous uploaded, i hope you understand!

Comment: i have solved the last problem modifing the view: `<!-- nasted images form -->
  <%= f.fields_for :images do |builder| %>
 <% if builder.object.new_record? %>
     <%= render 'image_fields', :f => builder %>
 <% end %>
  <% end %>


 <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Images", f, :images %></p>
 <!-- end nasted images form -->`

thanks so much @Michaël Witrant